# KafkaIO checkpoint persistence with Google Dataflow Runner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

I am trying to understand how the offsets and group management works with the Google Dataflow runner with KafkaIO reader. More specifically, I am trying to understand how offset management works:

- If the group.id config is set and if auto-commit and commitOffsetsInFinalize are disabled.
- If the group.id config is not set, how does offset and group management work?

Any code/document reference pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The KafkaIO reader is entirely part of Apache Beam. Google Cloud Dataflow does not treat this source differently than any other Beam source.

You can find its code at https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka (in various files). I don't know of any reference documentation other than the [Javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html).

Comment: If you check the documentation here -> https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html, the Partition Assignment and Checkpointing section says the following:

In summary, KafkaIO.read follows below sequence to set initial offset:
1. KafkaCheckpointMark provided by runner;

This to me indicates that the runner can maintain an internal state with checkpoint values.

Comment: The checkpoint mark is provided by the runner when it is resuming reading.

Comment: In that case, how is the runner maintaining the previous checkpoint values when resuming reading from the same topic?

Comment: The checkpoint mark is produced by KafkaIO and serialized. The runner's job is to store it and then provide it again later when KafkaIO is resumed.